# Is the time string of type String in the foreground transmitted to the background abnormally?

Tags: java, string, date

I perform query operations based on the time in the foreground, and pass the time string "2020-08-02 12:30:30" to the background, and the background console throws this error:

Prompt information:

```
default message [Failed to convert property value of type'java.lang.String' to required type'java.util.Date' for property'scanTime'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '2020-08-02 12:30:30'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Invalid format: "2020-08-02 12:30:30" is malformed at "12:30:30"]
```

This field in the database is of type date. I used the `"@DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)"` annotation in the front desk. Why does this error occur?

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso=DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) 
private Date scanTime;
```

Comment: ISO date format has a "T" separator between date and time values. (Instead you used a space...) Also you used `DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE`, which is a date only format...

Comment: Use classes of `java.time` instead of `java.util.Date`...